# Set different css styles for different components in vue-js project

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a vue- project with the following `src` directory tree

```
├── assets
|      └── moderator
|            └── css /* css styling for pages and components for moderators, e.g. everything is coloured blue*/
|      └── user
|            └── css /* css styling for pages and components for users, e.g. everything is coloured orage*/
├── components
|       └── moderator /* here are the .vue components for moderators' views */
|       └── user /* here are the .vue components for users' views*/

├── main.js
├── router.js
└── vue.config.js
```

The app will have two types of users :

1. Moderators
2. Users

Each type must have its own styling, components for *users* must use css-styles from `assets/user/css`, while *moderators'* from `assets/user/css`. 
If I use `scoped` import, styling doesn't propagate on external components like those of *Bootstrap*.

So my questions:

1. How to set different styling for respective components so that moderator will have everything in blue, and user - in orange?
2. Is it possible to set style programmatically depending on routes, defined in `router`?

Answer (score 1):

When you use Style in VueJS the css will render through all components. To use style only in the current component you need to uae `scoped`. This far you have done right, BUT! Bootstrap and other libraries mostly use components to represent their features so scoped will not work... But there is still a way! You can use `>>>` before the css you want to work in child-components. `>>>b-corousel {color=red;}`